# How to text a message to a number on an iPhone?

Tags: ios, iphone, messages, sms

On my iPhone 5, how do I text a message to a number? I am trying to send the words "HELLO WORLD" TO 888765?

Answer (score 1):

In iMessage

- create a new message (icon at top right)
- enter the number you want to send the message to into the To: line
- enter the message as usual
- send it